# Coding an xml file for all screens in android, but still some screens are showing result, while others not

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Different Screen preview]

Have followed all the rules, according to this http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

and have developed some pages based on this. But when coding for this page I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong here,while seeing preview of all screens, some screens are showing the proper result while some are not.

What can be reason for this much space above and below image banner that too in some screens while some are showing proper.

Here is the code snippet

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e4e6e3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#e4e6e3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/homeLinearButtons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="1.5dp"
            android:paddingRight="1.5dp" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp" >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/homeView_flipper"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/homeLinearButtons" >

            <!-- Layout 1 for 1st Screen -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/banner" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Layout 2 for 2nd Screen -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/banner2" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- Layout 3 for 3rd Screen -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/banner3" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ViewFlipper>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/homeLinearCategories"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/homeView_flipper"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#ffffff" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:text="All Categories"
                    android:textColor="#616161"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/homeBtnSeeMoreCat"
                    style="@style/btn_peacock_blue"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".4"
                    android:text="See More"
                    android:textColor="#095c49" />
            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/homeListCategories"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/homeLinearCategories"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/prod_card_view_bg"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/homeLinearRecommended"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/homeListCategories"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#ffffff" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:text="Recommended For You"
                    android:textColor="#616161"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/homeBtnSeeMoreRecom"
                    style="@style/btn_peacock_blue"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".4"
                    android:text="See More"
                    android:textColor="#095c49" />
            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/homeListRecommended"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/homeLinearRecommended"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/prod_card_view_bg"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're missing the attribute `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in your Banner `ImageView`.

#### Result:

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   android:src="@drawable/banner3" />
```

And right from the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) what this xml-attribute does:

> Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to
>   preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.

**Note:** In your first screenshot you can see that your *ImageView* blocks out an area greater than it's size (blue line). With *adjustViewBounds* the View will be wrapped properly.